# How to distinguish between sound coming from speaker and sound from "real" source?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

How to distinguish whether, say, a clarinet sound is coming from a speaker or from a real clarinet?

I assume the speaker will add some frequencies and possibly miss some (maybe it isn't able to vibrate at some frequencies?). Or maybe the sound emitted by a speaker has some other intrinsic acoustic characteristics that cannot be found on "real" sources?

To make matters worse, in my situation, it's not feasible to detect the real category of the sound, i.e., I should not classify the sound as clarinet, but rather should just state that the sound comes either from a speaker or from any other source, be it a clarinet or whatever. Thus I don't have a model of the sound to be played by the speaker.

(I'm not sure whether this is the right community to ask this question. Since it's about acoustic and wave properties, I thought you physics folks could help me out.)

Comment: Speakers create actual sound, so I'm really not sure if you _can_.  If you could, I think it may even fall into the domain of signal processing, not so much physics.  A sufficiently complicated speaker should theoretically be able to make the same air vibrations as an actual object, given enough knowledge.

Comment: -1. Unclear. Your question is too vague to answer definitely. With a poor quality speaker the difference is obvious to anyone. With a good speaker (or synthesizer) it may be impossible to tell the difference, even with a spectrum analyzer. There's a whole range of possibilities in between. Probably your question would be more appropriate on [Sound Design SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The problem is that it's not just the speaker but the entire recording (or PA) chain, e.g., microphone(s), pre-amp(s), and power amp(s) that are involved.

Comment: @JMac I thought so. Maybe I should resort not to signal processing but to machine learning techniques.

Comment: @sammygerbil Not sure why it's unclear. I was hoping there were some fundamental properties of sound waves emitted by speakers, either low- or high-quality ones.

Comment: There is no intrinsic characteristic in the sound from all speakers. Any distortion is due to the particular technology and the quality of components used in the speaker. So we cannot suggest something which will work for all speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether you mean distinguish by listening to the sound or by using objective measurements. Either way, there are several types of sound distortions while the most important of them are little known or understood.

There are two types of sound reproduction. They are similar to reproducing images as photographs and holograms. The difference is that the phase information is lost in photographs, but makes holograms three dimensional. So the most important distortion type is phase distortions. The phase is preserved in high quality stereo (two ears - two speakers). However the phase information is lost in multi-channel surround systems. Stereo is a hologram recreating the original wave. In contrast, surround creates new imaginary sound sources around you. Stereo is a window; surround is pictures on the walls.

The second class of distortions is timing. It refers to different types of timing errors, to which the human ear is overly sensitive. Of course, there are also dynamic, intermidulation, harmonic, saturation, and noise distortions (correlated and uncorrelated), as well as linear distortions.

Hope this helps a bit or at least points in the direction of further research.